# Pushing the PubMed Data to Kafka

Tags: python, ftp, apache-kafka, pubmed, kafka-python

In the PubMed Data Source, I need to push the Output into a Kafka queue..Each source could be viewed as a Kafka Topic. (I know the concepts in Kafka and explored Kafka using Python)

I am able to view the PubMed Data(s) through FireFTP.

Can anyone help how to proceed forward?

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use a service that downloads the data from FTP and spools it to Kafka. Apache Flume does exactly that. It' s quite easy to configure. You can either use a customer source for FTP https://github.com/keedio/flume-ftp-source or use a cron job that downloads the files to a spool dir and have flume pick up the files from there. Flume has a very decent Kafka Sink that allows writing continuously to kafka.